# Writing queries in Elasticsearch's Java client

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I used Elastic Search java client,
I am implementing a search application.
(Index has already been built)

I want to reproduce the Elastic Search java client, the following query.

However, it can not be reproduced.

If you are familiar with java client,
I want you to tell me.

## The query I want to execute (sample field has java and php)

```
{
    "Query": {
        "Bool": {
            "Must": [{
                "Match": {
                    "Sample": "java"
                }},
                {"Match": {
                    "Sample": "php"
                }
            }]
        }
    },
    "Size": 50
}
```

## Assembling queries on the java client

```
BoolQueryBuilder boolQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery ().
        Must (QueryBuilders.matchQuery ("sample", "test")));
SearchRequestBuilder builder = client.prepareSearch ()
        .setSize (50)
        .setQuery (boolQuery);
System.out.println (builder);
```

## ↑ Output contents of "builder" variable

```
{
  "Size": 50,
  "Query": {
    "Bool": {
      "Must": [
        {
          "Match": {
            "Sample": {
              "Query": "test",
              "Operator": "OR",
              "Prefix_length": 0,
              "Max_expansions": 50,
              "Fuzzy_transpositions": true,
              "Lenient": false,
              "Zero_terms_query": "NONE",
              "Boost": 1.0
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "Disable_coord": false,
      "Adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "Boost": 1.0
    }
  },
  "Ext": {}
}
```

When outputting, extra properties are included in match.
Moreover, I still do not know how to match multiple words.

Someone, please lend me your wisdom.

## Environment

- Language: Java 8
- Framework: Spring
- Elasticsearch client (jar) ver
    * Org.elasticsearch: 5.1.1
    * Org.elasticsearch.client: 5.1.1
- Elasticsearch's ver: 5.3.1

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I have a following mapping:

```
{
    "articles": {
        "mappings": {
            "article": {
                "properties": {
                    "sample": {
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I index following three documents:

```
{ "sample" : "java php" },
{ "sample" : "java" },
{ "sample" : "php" }
```

the es-query you provided gives me following result:

```
{
    "took": 1,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 1,
        "max_score": 0.51623213,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "articles",
                "_type": "article",
                "_id": "AV0rSbyjpRVEWsG0iTxj",
                "_score": 0.51623213,
                "_source": {
                    "sample": "java php"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

To get the same result with Java API, I use:

```
BoolQueryBuilder boolQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
        .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery ("sample", "java"))
        .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery ("sample", "php"));
SearchRequestBuilder builder = client.prepareSearch()
        .setSize(50)
        .setQuery(boolQuery);

SearchResponse response;
try {
    response = builder.execute().get();

    for (SearchHit hit : response.getHits().getHits()) {
        LOG.info("Result: " + hit.getSourceAsString());
    }
} catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
    // handle exception
    LOG.error("Exception while executing query {}", e);
}
```

Result:

```
Result: { "sample" : "java php" }
```

All the additional properties that you see in query while debugging are just the default values, Java API sets them explicitly.

Comment: thank you ! I am very grateful.
I was able to successfully implement.